# WCF Service client with "The server did not provide a meaningful reply..." exception

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, client-server, wcf-client

I have a Windows Service that hosts a WCF Service.  I also have a client that connects to it and messages are sent back and forth.  When I send a message from the client to the service the client catches the following excption:

> The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.

This is a little odd because I am not expecting the service to reply directly to the message sent by the client.  The service gets the message successfully, but then the client throws this exception and seems to lose its connection to the service.

Here is the Service app.config.  Disregard the bit about RESTfull service:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="OSAERest.api" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/api"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="OSAERest.IRestService"
                  behaviorConfiguration="WebHttp"/>
      </service>
      <service name="WCF.WCFService" behaviorConfiguration="WCFBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WCFBinding" contract="WCF.IWCFService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint
          address="mex"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCF/WCFService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="WCFBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="05:05:00" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="500" maxConcurrentSessions="500"
           maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebHttp">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WCFBinding">
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsDualHttpBinding>

    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="lib" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

And here is the client app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>

    <add key="ServiceIP" value="127.0.0.1"/>


  </appSettings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="lib" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IWCFService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          clientBaseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WCF/WCFService/"
          openTimeout="00:00:10" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:00:10"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"
          textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
          <security mode="None">
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCF/WCFService/"
        binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_IWCFService"
        contract="WCFService.IWCFService" name="WSDualHttpBinding_IWCFService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Why is the client catching this exception?

EDIT:

Here is the C# code where I am sending the message to the service if that helps:

```
WCFServiceClient wcfObj;
EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCF/WCFService/");
InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(this);
wcfObj = new Manager_WPF.WCFService.WCFServiceClient(context, "WSDualHttpBinding_IWCFService", ep);
wcfObj.Subscribe();

wcfObj.messageHost(message);
```

Comment: does this happen every time the client calls the service or after a few messages have been sent (or when multiple clients are running)

Comment: only one client is connected.  It happens every time I send a message to the service.

Comment: Can you show the contract and does the service attempt to make a callback to the client during the processing of the request?

Comment: Do you really need to create an instancecontext and pass it to the WCFServiceClient. I guess just using WCFServiceClient obj = new WCFServiceClient(); would be enough as it would by default map to the associated endpoint specified in the clients app.config unless you have multiple endpoints with same name.

Comment: did you fixed this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem with silverlight client and duplex tcp binding. The probem was caused by invoking callback to client right before returning from wcf method call. I've fixed this by putting callback invoke into background thread:

```
...
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
{                   
    //this notifies service subscribers (calls registered callbacks)                               
    OnConfigurationUpdated(EventArgs.Empty); 
});
return;
```