# Holding first service call and make second call in WCF from ASP.Net

Tags: wcf

I have a big doubt in WCF service call from a asp.net application. I implemented duplexchannel and call back contracts. I used conurrency mode is reentrant and instance mode = per session. I can make a call to wcf service and it will trigger the call back method. Untill this point, everything is good.

But i am thinking of a way like, when i make a first call to service, i hold that call in that service method using a waithandler object and triggered the call back method. This call back hits the client side code and again from the client side call  another method in the same service class to release that wait handler lock. When i used the wait handler to lock the first call and triggered the call back method, it is calling back to the client side and after that, it is again calling the another method in the same service. But i am getting time out exception...Holding the first call and making second call in the same service is possible ?? I am very new to ASP.Net

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract = typeof(IMyServiceCallBacks))]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData1();

    [OperationContract]
    void GetData2(bool isOK);
}


public interface IMyServiceCallBacks
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void MyCallBack();
}
```

This is the service class

```
 [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant)]
public class MyService : IMyService
{                
    EventWaitHandle waitHandle;
    bool isook = false;

    public MyService()
    {

    }

    string IMyService.GetData1()
    {            

        waitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);

        CallMethod();

        bool isOK = waitHandle.WaitOne();
        return "success";
    }

    private void CallMethod()
    {
        OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyServiceCallBacks>().MyCallBack();
    }

    public void GetData2(bool isOK)
    {
        isook = true;
        waitHandle.Reset();
    }

 }
```

Below is the client side code

```
 [CallbackBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant,  UseSynchronizationContext = false, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class MyProxyClient : MyService, MyServiceCallback
{

   bool isOK;
   private MyServiceClient caServiceProxy
   private InstanceContext myInstanceContext;

   public MyService()
   {

     myInstanceContext = new InstanceContext(this);
     EndpointAddress endPointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:2222222/MyWCF1/MyService.svc");

     caServiceProxy = new MyServiceClient(myInstanceContext, new WSDualHttpBinding(), endPointAddress);
   }

    public string GetData1()
    {
       string hhhh = caServiceProxy.GetData1();
       return hhhh;
    }

    public void GetData2(bool isOK)
    {
        caServiceProxy.GetData2(isOK);  // here it is processing but finally time out
    }

    // This is the call back
    public void MyCallBack()
    {
        isOK = true;
        GetData2(isOK);
    }   
 }
```

And below is the web config serviceModeltag

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="MyABService.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="WCFDuplex.Service1Behavior">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="MyABService.IMyService">         
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WCFDuplex.Service1Behavior">          
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>         
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

I used svcutil to generate proxy.
Any Idea ???

Thanks

Comment: It helps to post what code you have tried (or a summation of it).

Comment: the code used is added above. Any idea about it ?

Answer (score 0):

1) This is bad idea to rely on unstable channel and hold service method call. Calls shouldn't be long running. Therefore Http duplex based on periodical polling. TCP is better but for this kind of scenario I recommend to use operation with OneWay = true for Method1. Server can register clients, remember/manage states, do some work. And client must choose behavior according to callbacks. You can use AutoResetEvent/ManualResetEvent/TPL infrastructure for that background threads interchange/sync.

2)  I'm 90% sure that notifying client with callback inside service method with OneWay = false can cause errors. See for ex. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956169/wcf-service-client-with-the-server-did-not-provide-a-meaningful-reply-excep/13525894#13525894)

I wrote that you can avoid problems by deferring callback (Task.Factory.StartNew/QueueUserWorkItem etc.) to allow method to finish.